# OpenCl code works on a machine but I am getting CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS on another

Tags: c++, c, opencl

I had the following code, which works well on a machine but I when I try to run it on another machine with better graphics card I am getting errors:

```
global[0] = 512; global[1] = 512;
local [0] = 16; local [1] = 16;
ciErrNum = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, myKernel, 2, NULL, global, local, 0, NULL, &event);
```

**Errors:**

```
Error @ clEnqueueNDRangeKernel: CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS
Error @ clWaitForEvents: CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS
```

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Uh...so...what are the kernel arguments (and the kernel itself)?

Comment: @ChristianRau I finally found that keyword `__constant` that I used on the kernel work only on two of the three machines that I tried, I don't know why. When I changed it to `__global` on the kernel it works on the third.

Comment: Constant memory is a scarce and limited resource. Maybe your third device has very little constant memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How large are the buffer objects you are passing? `__constant` arguments are allocated from separate memory space and not from global memory so therefore you have probably ran out of constant memory.

The spec mandates that in full profile the device must support at minimum 4 `__constant` arguments with 64kB total in size. In embedded profile it's dropped to 1kB.

You can query the amount of constant memory available by checking the `CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE` using `clGetDeviceInfo`. Most likely your devices support way more than this minimum requirement.

In most cases you should use the constant buffer if you are able as in general it is quite a lot faster than global memory.

In future you should provide more information on your question. Because if the error is `CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS` one really needs to know what are the arguments to your kernel.

Comment: One amend: The minimum amount of constant memory is 16kB in the full spec (1.0 and 1.1). The version 1.2 states 64kB, but it is not available for all vendors.

Comment: You sure? Check http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.1.pdf and it states 64kB. Also http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.0.pdf states the same. However I did make one mistake. The amount of supported constant arguments must be 8 at minimum.

Comment: Sry my mistake, what I said applies to "local" memory not "constant" memory. Thank you for x-checking.

Comment: Wow, I had 2 days trying to figure out what was happening on a similar case... it was the 64kb limit for the constant memory (which I didn't know about). Thanks, @sharpneli